# failing to echo max with php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Thanks in advance for any help and understanding with the fact that I'm still very inexperienced...

Despite a long search through questions and examples, I still can't properly query/echo MAX.

If you could show me an exact example of the proper code I'd be very grateful.

Since I think I understand (?) you cannot mix mysql with mysqli, I'm going to provide here a sample of my code that actually works for purpose other than getting the max value:

```
$query = "SELECT iltr FROM massimo_demo_copy WHERE UPDT=3";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$LTR = $row['iltr'];

echo "$LTR;
```

again, this code example works but it's not what I'm trying to do. What I am trying to do is get the maximum value from another column (points). I've tried too many syntax versions to list them...

I just wanna echo the max value from the points column with a mysqli syntax that is compatible with the example of the type of code above.

this is the first version I tried and it fails:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(points) FROM massimo_demo_copy";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$maxpts = $row['points'];

echo $maxpts;
```

I tried many others but lers start with that one

Thanks

Comment: We can't tell you what is wrong with your code if you don't show us the code that isn't working, please update your question to include the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: Why you are adding the working code ? . we don't need that , just give the code which is not working.

Comment: start from selecting max value in plain mysql

Comment: why not to try to get exactly what you selected? namely $maxpts = $row['MAX(points)']

Comment: omg. of course. THANK YOU your common sense! it works. i'm an idiot, but hey... anyway thanks again, have a great one!

Answer (score 0):

Your `$query` should look something like this `SELECT MAX(points) as points FROM massimo_demo_copy`

Comment: $query = "SELECT MAX(points) FROM massimo_demo_copy";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$maxpts = $row['points'];

echo $maxpts;

Comment: sorry i didnt know how to format in the comment section and accidentally posted. i put the same in the question.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question, I resolved like this:

```
$example_max_value = "SELECT max(value) as max_value FROM table WHERE tableid={$var_ID}";
$get_result = mysqli_query($conectionDB,$example_max_value);
$get_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_result);
$max_value = $get_result["max_value"];
```

Output:
max_value in the DB from table where table has the especifically range